# Update SQL Server XML data with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xml-namespaces

I have a temp table where I assemble various values. Once these values are assembled I want to query the table to generate an XML element that will be inserted to update a larger XML data in a table column. Here is my TSQL I am using.

```
DECLARE @AssignmentAttachmentsXML AS XML

SET @AssignmentAttachmentsXML = (
SELECT
    TaxId AS '@AssignmentId',
    AttachmentId AS '@AttachmentDbId',
    Folder AS '@Folder',
    IIAP AS '@IIAP',
    AttachmentName AS '@AttachmentName',
    IIAPDate AS '@IIAPDate',
    AddToAssignmentDate AS '@AttachmentAddedDate',
    AttachmentAddedBy AS '@AttachmentAddedBy',
    CentralPrintDate AS '@CentralPrintDate',
    PostToCoreDate AS '@PostToCoreDate'
FROM @TempAttachmentDataTable
FOR XML PATH('Attachment'), ROOT('Attachments'));

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://MtwUiTaxDataSchema' AS "MTW")
UPDATE compas.tbTaxAssignmentSequence
    SET xmlAssignment.modify('insert sql:variable("@AssignmentAttachmentsXML") into (/MTW:MtwUiTax/MTW:Assignment)[1]')
FROM
compas.tbTaxAssignment 
    INNER JOIN
        compas.tbTaxAssignmentSequence
            ON
                compas.tbTaxAssignment.fkbintCurrentSequence = compas.tbTaxAssignmentSequence.bintId
where compas.tbTaxAssignment.bintId = @AssignmentId;
```

The result is this code inserts an XML element with an xmlns="" attribute in the "Attachments" element.

```
<Attachments xmlns="">
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="72" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="73" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="75" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="88" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="89" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="90" ...
</Attachments>
```

The empty string in the xmlns attribute messes up downstream XPATH queries.

How can I update the FOR XML PATH query to create the XML without the xmlns attribute, like this:

```
<Attachments>
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="72" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="73" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="75" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="88" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="89" ...
  <Attachment AssignmentId="10166" AttachmentDbId="90" ...
</Attachments>
```

-- Example Test Script Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - 13.0.1742.0 (X64) ---

```
CREATE TABLE AssignmentTable
    (
        bintId BIGINT NULL, 
        xmlAssignment XML NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AssignmentTable]
               ([bintId]
               ,[xmlAssignment])
         VALUES (
            1, 
            '<MtwUiTax xmlns="http://MtwUiTaxDataSchema"><Assignment id="10404"><Stuff/></Assignment></MtwUiTax>')
    SELECT [xmlAssignment] FROM AssignmentTable
    ----------------------------------------------------
    GO
    CREATE TABLE AttachmentTable
    (
        bintId BIGINT NULL, 
        Attrib1 VARCHAR(20),
        Attrib2 VARCHAR(20),
        Attrib3 VARCHAR(20),
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AttachmentTable]
               ([bintId]
               ,[Attrib1]
               ,[Attrib2]
               ,[Attrib3])
         VALUES
               (1
               ,'Attachment 1'
               ,'Apple'
               ,'Red'),
               (2
               ,'Attachment 2'
               ,'Grape'
               ,'Purple'),
               (3
               ,'Attachment 3'
               ,'Pear'
               ,'Green')
    SELECT * FROM AttachmentTable
    ----------------------------------------------------
    GO
    DECLARE @AssignmentAttachmentsXML AS XML
    SET @AssignmentAttachmentsXML = (SELECT bintId AS '@Id',
                                            Attrib1 AS '@Attrib1',
                                            Attrib2 AS '@Attrib2',
                                            Attrib3 AS '@Attrib3'
                                        FROM AttachmentTable
                                        FOR XML PATH('Attachment'), ROOT('Attachments'));
    SELECT @AssignmentAttachmentsXML;
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://MtwUiTaxDataSchema' AS "MTW")
                    UPDATE AssignmentTable
                        SET xmlAssignment.modify('insert sql:variable("@AssignmentAttachmentsXML") into (/MTW:MtwUiTax/MTW:Assignment)[1]')
                    FROM
                        AssignmentTable
                    WHERE
                        bintId = 1
    SELECT [xmlAssignment] FROM AssignmentTable
    -- CLEAN UP ----------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE AttachmentTable
    DROP TABLE AssignmentTable
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Just create the elements of @AssignmentAttachmentsXML in the same namespace as of the target element into which @AssignmentAttachmentsXML is inserted later on:

```
DECLARE @AssignmentAttachmentsXML AS XML

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://MtwUiTaxDataSchema')
SELECT @AssignmentAttachmentsXML = (
SELECT
    TaxId AS '@AssignmentId',
    AttachmentId AS '@AttachmentDbId',
    Folder AS '@Folder',
    IIAP AS '@IIAP',
    AttachmentName AS '@AttachmentName',
    IIAPDate AS '@IIAPDate',
    AddToAssignmentDate AS '@AttachmentAddedDate',
    AttachmentAddedBy AS '@AttachmentAddedBy',
    CentralPrintDate AS '@CentralPrintDate',
    PostToCoreDate AS '@PostToCoreDate'
FROM @TempAttachmentDataTable
FOR XML PATH('Attachment'), ROOT('Attachments'));
.............
```

Answer (score 0):

In your response you are selecting the variable @AssignmentAttachmentsXML I am assigning a value to @AssignmentAttachmentsXML that is used later in the xmlAssignment.modify statement. When I add the default xmlnamespaces the following "WITH" statement creates a syntax error. Apparently "SET" and "SELECT" do not handle the "WITH XMLNAMESPACES" the same.